# receiving a json response with vue.js2 in laravel

Tags: json, vuejs2, laravel-5.4, vue-component

sending a request and getting response which bases on it i want to chege the status and display something different, can't figure out what's the problem, the route seems to be working fine and I'm receiving a response which looks like this  [image]

I'm trying to access this using Vue component and I'm getting that error status is not defined, here is my Vue component

```
<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
                axios.get('/userfound/' + this.profile_user_id)
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    this.status = response.data.status;                   
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                  });
                },
        props: ['profile_user_id'],
        data(){
            return {
                status: ''
            }        
        },
        methods:{
            add_friend(){
                // this.loading = false
                axios.get('/add_friend/' + this.profile_user_id)
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    if (response.data == 1) {
                        this.status = 'waiting'
                    }

                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                  });
                }
            }
        }
</script>
```

why am i getting this error: `TypeError: cannot read property 'status' of undefined ..`
i've tried `"this.status = response.body.status"` and `"this.status = response.data.status"` but neither is working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe there is an issue with the scope of a variable. Try below answer:

```
<script>
export default {
    mounted() {
            var self = this;
            axios.get('/userfound/' + self.profile_user_id)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                self.status = response.data.status;                   
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
              });
            },
    props: ['profile_user_id'],
    data(){
        return {
            status: ''
        }        
    },
    methods:{
        add_friend(){
            // you can do same here as well
            var self = this;
            axios.get('/add_friend/' + self.profile_user_id)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                if (response.data == 1) {
                    self.status = 'waiting'
                }
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
              });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: it works while im in the current page but when i refresh it puts the same error

Comment: That's strange. Try debugging with chrome devtools.

Comment: i have posted that code up here and it works, i have no idea why, and it's logging the right value out, but when i try to test with it, it doesnt seem to work, check what i posted out

Comment: this is wrong `status = response.data.status`. The variable status is not referring to the `status` you created in `data` in your component.

Comment: i changed it back to status = response.body.status and it started displaying the error again

Comment: Of course, it will. Please do what i did in the provided answer.

Comment: i did and still getting this error, TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141827/discussion-between-pradeepb-and-mohamed-gabr).